# If strncat adding NUL may cause the array go out of bound

Tags: c

I have some trouble with strncat().The book called Pointers On C says the function ,strncat(),always add a NUL in the end of the character string.To better understand it ,I do an experiment.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(void)
{
    char a[14]="mynameiszhm";
    strncat(a,"hello",3);
    printf("%s",a);
    return 0;
}
```

The result is mynameiszhmhel
In this case the array has 14 char memory.And there were originally 11 characters in the array except for NUL.Thus when I add three more characters,all 14 characters fill up the memory of array.So when the function want to add a NUL,the NUL takes up memory outside the array.This cause the array to go out of bounds but the program above can run without any warning.Why?Will this causes something unexpected?
So when we use the strncat ,should we consider the NUL,in case causes the array go out of bound?
And I also notice the function strncpy don't add NUL.Why this two string function do different things about the same thing?And why the designer of C do this design?

Comment: "*the program above can run without any warning*". Are you expecting warnings during compile time or during runtime? The language does not guarantee either of those. C (for better or worse) allows you to shoot yourself in  the foot in many ways. In this case, overflowing the buffer results in Undefined Behaviour. UB means it can crash, get wrong results, appear to "work" or any other behaviour.

Comment: When in doubt just add on a couple of extra bytes. Nothing too large, just round it to the next power of 4 or 8. Unless you are writing code for an embedded system, memory is usually quite cheap. It is generally better/easier to be certain you wont cause undefined behavior than to need to debug it later.

Comment: If you turn on the warning then it will produce an error message when you run it: https://godbolt.org/z/a7WG77dGW

Comment: I guess I don't understand the question.  If strncat's docs say it ALWAYS adds a `\0` that space isn't accounted for in the size you pass to strncat then you need to account for it.

Comment: The interface to `strncat()` is counter-intuitive.  In particular, you cannot use `strncat(target, source, sizeof(target))` safely, even if the target string is currently empty — it will write beyond the end of the target string if the source string is too big.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This cause the array to go out of bounds but the program above can run without any warning. Why?

Maybe.  With `strncat(a,"hello",3);`, code attempted to write beyond the 14 of `a[]`.  It *might* go out of bounds, it might not.  It is *undefined behavior* (UB).  Anything is allowed.

---

> Will this causes something unexpected?

Maybe, the behavior is not defined.  It *might* work just as you expect - whatever that is.

---

> So when we use the`strncat` ,should we consider the NUL, in case causes the array go out of bound?

Yes, the size parameter needs to account for appending a *null character*, else UB.

---

> I also notice the function strncpy don't add NUL. Why this two string function do different things about the same thing? And why the designer of C do this design?

The 2 functions `strncpy()/strncat()` simple share similar names, not highly similar paired functionality of `strcpy()/strcat()`.

Consider that the early 1970s, memory was far more expensive and many considerations can be traced back to a byte of memory more that an hour's wage.  Uniformity of functionality/names was of lesser importance.

---

> And there were originally 11 characters in the array except for NUL.

More like "And there were originally 11 characters in the array except for 3 NUL.".  This is no partial initialization in C.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really an answer, but a counterexample.

Observe the following modification to your program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(void)
{
    char p[]="***";
    char a[14]="mynameiszhm";
    char q[]="***";
    strncat(a,"hello",3);
    printf("%s%s%s", p, a, q);
    return 0;
}
```

The results of this program are dependent on where `p` and `q` are located in memory, compared to `a`. If they are not adjacent, the results are not so clear but if either `p` or `q` immediately comes after `a`, then your `strncat` will overwrite the first `*` causing one of them not to be printed anymore because that will now be a string of length `0`.

So the results are dependent on memory layout, and it should be clear that the compiler can put the variables in memory in any order it likes. And they can be adjacent or not.

So the problem is that you are not keeping to your promise not to put more than 14 bytes into `a`. The compiler did what you asked, and the C standards guarantee behaviour as long as you keep to the promises.

And now you have a program that may or may not do what you wanted it to do.